# Cronjob: Run Python script on server in virtual env

Tags: python, cron, virtualenv

I went through tons of questions and answers in the net. However, I couldnt make my code work. So sorry for raising this question as so many others did.

I have a python script in my directory:

```
test_codes/test_mail/test_crawler.py
```

I have my virtualenv in:

```
.virtualenvs/test_crawler/bin/python
```

So I have set up a cronjob like this:

```
* * * * * .virtualenvs/test_crawler/bin/python test_codes/test_mail/test_crawler.py > /test_codes/test_mail/cronlogs.log 2>&1
```

I have two troubles with that:

1. The script should send me an test mail, which I do not receive (manually starting the script works fine(
2. The cronlog-file does not appear. Do I need to create this one first? In my opinion this file will be created when executing the first cronjob

Thanks for help in advance

Comment: have you managed to solve this? I'm facing the same issue...

Answer (score 0):

First try this :

1. cd to the folder where your script is (.py file)
2. activate your virtualenv
3. launch python3 with script

Start with an easier cronjob first to see if it works :
Make a `test.py` file :

```
import datetime

with open("test.txt", mode="a") as file:
    file.write(str(datetime.datetime.now())+"\n")
```

Add this your cron, make sure you have the right path for the virtualenv

```
* * * * * cd ~/test_codes/test_email && ../venv/bin/python3 test.py > /tmp/cronlog_test.txt 2>&1
```

Path :

```
test_codes
└── venv
└── test_email
    └── test.py
```

Regarding your 2nd question, the `cronlog_test.txt` will be generated with the cronjob